# fetch leads whos id match with Campagain

Tags: soql

Query

```
Select id,name,phone,email,CampaignMember 
from lead 
where CampaignMember=:selectedcampaign
```

Error

> No such column 'CampaignMember' on entity 'Lead'. If you are attempting to use a custom field, be sure to append the '__c' after the custom field name. Please reference your WSDL or the describe call for the appropriate names.

Please help me to modify this.

Comment: here "selectedcampaign" is campaign id

Comment: What is the condition that you are trying to form here and fetch the lead records?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use
`select Id, Name, Phone, Email from Lead where Id in (select LeadId from CampaignMember where CampaignId = :selectedcampaign)`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get lead details which is part of a campaign then you will have to query CampaignMember records first where LeadId is matching and then do another query on lead based on the found lead Ids.

```
Set<Id> lstLeadIds = new Set<Id>();
for(CampaignMember cm : [SELECT LeadId FROM CampaignMember WHERE CampaignId =:campaignId ) {
    lstLeadIds.add(cm.LeadId); 
}

//Query lead records 
List<Lead> lstLeads = [SELECT Id, Name, Phone, Email FROM Lead WHERE Id IN :lstLeadIds];
```